# Cypher: return a string if no match using fulltext search

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('myIndex', 'coding')
YIELD node
RETURN node
```

which returns the `coding` node if the index actually matches with any existing nodes, and return null if there is no match.

Instead of returning a null value if there is no match, I want to return a string or a message like `No match found`.

I was thinking I can combine `apoc.when()` like

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('myIndex', 'coding')
YIELD node

WITH node
CALL apoc.when(node is not null, 'RETURN node', 'RETURN "No match found"', {node:node})
```

but I get an error

```
Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 5, column 1 (offset: 77))
"CALL apoc.when(node is not null, 'RETURN node', 'RETURN "No match found"', {node:node})"
```

I tried adding

```
YIELD value
RETURN value
```

at the end of the statement, but it does not return the message when there is no match and works as if the `apoc.when()` is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that after `YIELD` returns null, all the operations after that are not computed (similar to how MATCH vs OPTIONAL MATCH work).

I was able to overcome this by creating a collection, unwind with case, and coalesce as Tomaz suggested in his answer.

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('myIndex', 'coding')
YIELD node
WITH collect(node) as nodes
UNWIND (CASE nodes WHEN [] then [null] else nodes end) as n
RETURN coalesce(n, "No match found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use coalesce:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('myIndex', 'coding')
YIELD node
RETURN coalesce(node, "No match found") as result
```

Comment: I tried this but the response is still empty